# Как добавить транзитную точку в маршрут. (yandex api)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

У меня есть две точки A - начало маршрута и B - конец маршрута. Yandex карта сама прокладывает маршрут. Я же хочу проложить свой индивидуальный маршрут и я предполагаю, что для этого в маршрут надо добавить транзитные точки.

---

Вот код

```
function init () {

  // Создаем карту с добавленными на нее кнопками.
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.750625, 37.626],
    zoom: 14
  });

  // Создаем мультимаршрут и добавляем его на карту.
  var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
      referencePoints: [
        [60.013937, 30.649144], // Точка A
        [59.995717, 30.650495], // Это должно быть транзитной точкой.
        [59.995299, 30.649991], // Это должно быть транзитной точкой.
        [59.991251, 30.646315], // Это должно быть транзитной точкой.
        [59.991116, 30.643977], // Это должно быть транзитной точкой.
        [59.984847, 30.644900]  // Точка B
      ]
  }, {
      editorDrawOver: false,
      wayPointDraggable: true,
      viaPointDraggable: true,
      // Задаем собственное оформление линий мультимаршрута.
      routeStrokeColor: "000088",
      routeActiveStrokeColor: "ff0000",
      pinIconFillColor: "ff0000",
      boundsAutoApply: true,
      zoomMargin: 30
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);

}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

Этот же код но на codepen https://codepen.io/zilermand/pen/MGQPOO

---

P.s. Я пробовал гуглить, а еще я читал документацию. Я разобрался как это сделать в router, но в multiRouter это делается как-то по другому.

---

P.s.s. Я очень буду рад если вы покажете на примере :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить: `params: {viaIndexes: [1,2,3,4]}` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvJPgq
Добавлю ещё ссылку на соответсвующий пример в песочнице апи карт: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_view_options

Comment: Большое спасибо :D